# how to run the EC2 snitch configuration in cassandra

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, backpressure

I am trying to accomplish a single cassandra node start up in Ec2 snitch configuration.

The yaml properties I have changed for this configuration is:

```
seeds : 'ip-address of machine'
listen: 'ip_address of machine'
rpc_address:'ip_address of machine'
snitch : Ec2Snitch
```

All other thrift, rpc_broadcast, broadcast are all commented and are not enabled.

I am getting this error when I am trying to start the connection

> INFO  [main] 2017-12-04 16:54:15,021 RateBasedBackPressure.java:123 -
>   Initialized back-pressure with high ratio: 0.9, factor: 5, flow: FAST,
>   window size: 2000. INFO  [main] 2017-12-04 16:54:15,022
>   DatabaseDescriptor.java:725 - Back-pressure is disabled with strategy
>   org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9,
>   factor=5, flow=FAST}. Exception
>   (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered
>   during startup: Error instantiating snitch class
>   'org.apache.cassandra.locator.Ec2Snitch'.
>   org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Error
>   instantiating snitch class 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.Ec2Snitch'.
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.construct(FBUtilities.java:543)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.construct(FBUtilities.java:521)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.createEndpointSnitch(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1035)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applySnitch(DatabaseDescriptor.java:959)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyAll(DatabaseDescriptor.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.applyConfig(CassandraDaemon.java:645)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:580)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:689)
>   Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host
>   unreachable)  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)  at
>   sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:242)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)  at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
>     at
>   java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.locator.Ec2Snitch.awsApiCall(Ec2Snitch.java:78)
>     at org.apache.cassandra.locator.Ec2Snitch.(Ec2Snitch.java:55)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)  at
>   org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.construct(FBUtilities.java:528)
>     ... 8 more ERROR [main] 2017-12-04 16:54:18,308
>   CassandraDaemon.java:706 - Exception encountered during startup
>   org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Error
>   instantiating snitch class 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.Ec2Snitch'.
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.construct(FBUtilities.java:543)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.construct(FBUtilities.java:521)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.createEndpointSnitch(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1035)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applySnitch(DatabaseDescriptor.java:959)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyAll(DatabaseDescriptor.java:318)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:142)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.applyConfig(CassandraDaemon.java:645)
>   [apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]  at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:580)
>   [apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]  at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:689)
>   [apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1] Caused by:
>   java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:242)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.locator.Ec2Snitch.awsApiCall(Ec2Snitch.java:78)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.locator.Ec2Snitch.(Ec2Snitch.java:55)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.construct(FBUtilities.java:528)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]     ... 8 common frames omitted

I was unable to figure out the initial cause of error. I already checked initialising any properties in rack-dc and topology-properties file. But I didn't find anything worth to cause this issue.
The node is not even initialising the initial schema also. Can anyone please help me to overcome this issue? If possible, help me in giving instructions setting up a multi node setup also in Ec2 snitch configuration. I have tried all the possible ways to establish the single node with Ec2 configuration. So, I thought to post it in SO and let the big brains help me in solving the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo in your post, but you need a space after `rpc_address:`

Comment: Yeah. Its just a typo here. There is no problem regarding this. Anyway thanks for your effort

Comment: This works for me in the yaml file
cluster_name: 'tomer-test-cluster'
seeds: "[internal_ip]"
listen_address: [internal_ip]
native_transport_port: 9042
endpoint_snitch: Ec2Snitch
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
rpc_port: 9160
broadcast_rpc_address: [internal_ip]

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you (I tested it) - check for typos, or missing chars / spaces in your yaml file.

- cluster_name: 'tomer-test-cluster'
- seeds: "[internal_ip]"
- listen_address: [internal_ip]
- native_transport_port: 9042
- endpoint_snitch: Ec2Snitch
- rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
- rpc_port: 9160
- broadcast_rpc_address: [internal_ip]